# Android kotlin: trying to share images to google photos

Tags: android, kotlin

my first post here, hope i'm doing it right:

I am trying to build an app to help my parents save the pictures they get on whatssup - to google photos (and avoid saving lots of dad-jokes and stuff)

so i learned a little kotlin and made an app to show the images in the whatssup folder - but when i try to share them to google photos - it just crashes.
(although it does show the images in the recyclerview, so i guess the path is correct)

here's the code i tried to use:

```
  private fun shareFile(path : String) {
        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "image/*"
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  Uri.parse("file://" + path))
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Image Using"))
    }
```

also, would appreciate tips how to directly send multiple images to google photos without the selection menu.

thanks !

Comment: `Uri.parse("file://" + path))` That will not work. Use FileProvider to get an uri for your file and to serve your file. Further you should have shown value of path variable.

Comment: do i need to give file provider the URI to the whatssup image directory ?

Comment: now... can you help me more?
how do i send a list of files to google photos without opening the sharing menu for each file? or better - not opening the sharing menu at all?